# Redirect olddomain querystring layout to newdomain and new querystring layout?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

OK, say my blog site `myurl.org` as many links to a separate domain:

```
old.myurl.org?oldvar=foo
```

Only `old.myurl.org` no longer exists and has been replaced by `new.myurl.org`.

If the query string vars were the same on `new.myurl.org`, I believe I could rewrite from `.htaccess` using:

```
RewirteCond %{http_host} ^old.myurl.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new.myurl.org [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The only problem is that I also need to change the query string var from `oldvar` to `newvar` and preserve it's data (foo).

There are plenty of examples of how to rewrite query string vars in different ways, but I can't seem to find an example of this scenario.

I need to rewrite:

```
old.myurl.org?oldvar=foo
```

To:

```
new.myurl.org?newvar=foo
```

**Edit**

Furthermore, I have several potential query string key values to account for, but not all will always be present.

So I may need:

```
old.myurl.org?oldvar=foo&oldvar2=bar --> new.myurl.org?newvar=foo&newvar2=bar
```

or

```
old.myurl.org?oldvar2=bar --> new.myurl.org?newvar2=bar
```

This may not even be possible, but in one case I need to strip off part of the query string value.  So `?oldvar=foo{term}` might need to become `?newvar=foo`

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First condition match the domain, second condition match the query string and the rule will match your domain root:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.myurl\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldvar=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar=%1 [R=301,L]
```

You can place more than one query string as well:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.myurl\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldvar=(\w+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldvar=(\w+)&oldvar2=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar=%1&newvar2=%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.myurl\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^oldvar2=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar2=%1 [R=301,L]
```

To use a path like `x/y/z` as you have mentioned on the comment you change the `RewriteRule` for example the rule we are currently using, will only redirect from `yourdomain.com/?...` which is:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar2=%1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to catch a different path you would do this:

```
RewriteRule ^x/?$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar2=%1 [R=301,L]
```

The above would catch `yourdomain.com/x?...` and `yourdomain.com/x/?...`

You can have more than one path as well and use a OR condition like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(x|x/y|x/y/z)/?$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar2=%1 [R=301,L]
```

The above means we want to match `x/?...` OR `x?...` OR `x/y?...` and `x/y/?...` OR `x/y/z?...` OR `x/y/z/?...`

By encapsulating it on the parenthesis and using the `|` as separator and OR.

The `^` and `$` means match from begin to end, so when it contains nothing means match nothing which means root folder `domain.com/`, when there is content it will match the content for instance `domain.com/x` or whatever you place into it.

Comment: @AaronWaller [kindly mark it as the right answer if it solves your problem, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: Question though...  if the %{QUERY_STRING} condition is not met will the rewrite rule still apply the domain rewrite?  Also, I have several potential query string keys that I must account for, none of which are guaranteed. I'll edit the original question with an example...

Comment: @AaronWaller no, if any of the conditions are not met it will not apply, you may however make more conditions. Will update with an example.

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  I can start a new thread if it is out of scope for this question, but it would also be great if I could drop "{term}" from oldvar=foo{term}

Comment: @AaronWaller is term enclosed by `{}` or can you provide a better example ?

Comment: Yes it is enclosed like: ?oldvar=1117700{CKEY}.  The numeric value, and length changes, but "{CKEY}" is always attached.

Comment: @AaronWaller I don't think it would catch `{CKEY}` because `\w+` only catch alphanumeric and underscore so it would stop at the character before `{`

Comment: You have saved me countless hours... Thanks. Can I append the RewriteCond to include any other path on old.myurl.org?  For example: `old.myurl.org/x/y/z?oldvar=foo` or `old.myurl.org/a/b?oldvar=foo`.  As written it only works for exactly `old.myurl.org?oldvar=foo` </br> Also, oldvar=foo currently validates and redirects properly, but oldvar=foo{CKEY} does not.  Were you inferring that the rules as written would simply fail when the `{` was reached?  Or that it would discard everything from the `{` on and simply pass `foo`?

Comment: @AaronWaller x/y/z would go on the `RewriteRule`, for example `RewriteRule ^x/y/z/?$ http://new.myurl.org/?newvar=%1 [R=301,L]` will update with a detailed example.